# Theano : Installation of CUDA

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, theano-cuda

I have installed CUDA Toolkit V 7.0 and its graphics driver version is 347.62. In my theano code

```
import os
os.environ['THEANO FLAGS']= 'mode=FAST RUN,device= gpu, lib.cnmem = 1,floatX=float32'
```

I used this. Its showing the following error.\n

> You forced the use of gpu device gpu, but CUDA initialization failed
>   with error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: CUDA driver
>   version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version'

What should I do?

Comment: what GPU do you have?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750 M @talonmies

Comment: probably you should install CUDA correctly, and verify that it is installed correctly